# Arduino creating delay function

Tags: c, time

I am trying to make my own delay function. Briefly `mydelay` function is calling `toggled` function every `secs` seconds. The code is not well written, i know (this is the first version). But i am just trying to get it work properly. Then i will refactor it. But i have some unexpected bugs. First time the loop in `x` function is working properly. It is printing "I am in while" for 1 second and then it prints "Im ending mydelay" which is the behaviour i want. But after finishing the loop in `x`. The second time when it loops. It enters the `mydelay` function (that is ok). But then it is not printing "I am in while" at all. It just prints "Im ending mydelay" which is not good.

Here is the code:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
int led = 7;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  x();
  Serial.println("Im ending main loop");
}

void x() {
  for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    mydelay(led, 0, 1);
    mydelay(led, 1, 1);
  }
}

void mydelay(int pin, int hol, int secs) {
  int starttime = millis();
  while ((millis() - starttime) <= (secs * 1000)) Serial.println("I am in while");
  toggled(pin, hol);
  Serial.println("Im ending mydelay");
}

void toggled(int pin, int hol) {
  digitalWrite(led, hol);
}
```

Comment: 1) `starttime` should be `unsigned long`. 2) it is a bad idea to `Serial.println()` inside a tight loop: you will fill the output buffer and be slowed down by the prints.

Comment: [You already asked this exact question on Stackoverflow.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40533507/arduino-creating-delay-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your main problem is you declare `starttime` as an `int`. This is a signed value with a range of -32,768 to 32,767. You will quickly overflow - in about 32 seconds.

The solution is to use an `unsigned long` which has a range of 0 to 4,294,967,295.

Comment: Yeah,actually i asked the exactly the same question on stackoverflow.And got my answer.But anyways i appreciate the answer.

Comment: Btw,Isnt range of int on arduino 65536-1 ?

Comment: @MuhamedCicak That would be for `unsigned int`. Without specifying `unsigned` you get a signed int.

Comment: True... I forgot that,i am pretty new to C so yea.I am reading this K&R Book.I dont know if you know it.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something along these lines:

```
void verboseDelay(unsigned long ms)
{
    unsigned long now = millis();
    Serial.print(F("delaying"));
    unsigned long start = now, lastPrintTime = now;
    do {
        now = millis();
        if (now - lastPrintTime >= 20) {
            Serial.write('.');
            lastPrintTime += 20;
        }
    } while (now - start < ms);
    Serial.println();
}
```

The trick is to used `unsigned long` for all the time-related variables,
and also to avoid printing too fast.